# How can other developer's apps know they have shared files with my app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I'm designing an app that registers it's own UTI. When another developer's app shares a file with this type how do they know that it's definitely my app that has been opened?

At the moment the activity type that is returned in the sharing apps 'UIActivityItemSource' is 'com.apple.UIKit.activity.RemoteOpenInApplication-ByCopy'.

But if it's the Notes app, for instance, the activity type is 'com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension'. How do I register a unique activity type that the sharing app can receive?

```swift
/* 
Example of how the other developers would be sharing data to my app 
after calling UIActivityViewController with this OtherDevelopersAppActivityItemSource 
*/
class OtherDevelopersAppActivityItemSource: NSObject, UIActivityItemSource {            
    func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivityType?) -> Any?
    {        
        guard let _activityType = activityType else { return nil }

        // this is probably my app that the user has selected??
        if _activityType.rawValue == "com.apple.UIKit.activity.RemoteOpenInApplication-ByCopy" {
            return "a large amount of data from the other developers app for my app"
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }        
}
```

I expected the activityType variable to be 'com.mycompany.myapp' or something designating which app has been selected.